# How can i hide list entries based on user roles Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm quite new to Drupal, i setup node pages and assigned edit permission to various roles. Within the edit options i have a select list field with dropdown options red green blue yellow

What i'm looking at is to restrict each role from viewing items within a dropdown list.

Example: 
Student role will see
red blue

Teacher role will see
red green

Admin role will see
red green blue yellow

I searched and seems like Entity Reference is the way togo but i can not set it up correctly. A. detail step by step help would be really appreciated

update: code need help

DONE!

the following worked for me...

My form name is cal_form, field name is field_color

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {

switch ($form_id)  {
    case 'cal_form': 
    global $user;
//check role
    if (in_array('student', $user->roles)) {

//student role will not see the following entries       
unset($form['field_color'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']['green']);
unset($form['field_color'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']['yellow']);
   }
    break; 
  } 
}
```

Added the above as php code as mymodule.module and activated it.

Comment: Where is the dropdown list placed? In what form?

Comment: Its a node, within the edit options i have a select list field

Comment: Inside that $form array find your field and options array and remove unwanted values depending on user role. But be careful - this is ok for creating new nodes but think about editing. What if option that is not allowed for current user is already selected? (Or you solved this with permissions)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is a simple options list field then your simplest option is probably altering the edit form yourself with [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) (hook_from_FORM_ID_alter is better as it will only run for that particular form).
If you use a taxonomy reference field instead, you could use [taxonomy access](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) or [taxonomy access lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite).

Comment: My form name is event-node-form, field name is  field_display[und]

need help with the code
`
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'event-node-form') {
  if (!user_access('administer nodes')) {
      
      //what to add here
    }
  }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom module. In this module you should implement [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to intercept the form before being shown, list the roles of the current user (in $user -> roles) and then filter all those options you do not want to be displayed.